# csv to html (multi rows)

Tags: python, pandas

I’m trying to convert a csv file to html file using Pandas. I was able to get it done with this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('order.csv', header=None, sep='\n')
df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)

df.to_html('order.html')
```

and the html file looks like this

[image: and the html file looks like this]

The issue is that the csv file will grow and it will add additional data in the same row when we have a repeat customer like below.

more data added in the same row

[image: more data added in the same row]

It’s going to be a problem when someone places 1000 orders. Can anyone help so that I can have the html file as the format below?

this is what i'm trying to acheive

[image: this is what i'm trying to acheive]

Comment: This doesn’t look like an issue with html output to me, have you checked that your DataFrame you get from the CSV doesn’t have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do

```py
df.to_html('order.html', sparsify=False)
```

as per the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)